# Copy file into install directory of metro-style-app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5

Is there a way to copy a file (selected with filepicker) to the installdir of the currently running metro style app? I tried to get the InstallationFolder with:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
```

But I always get the following error while getting InstalledLocation:

`Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.`

Is this maybe a problem with debugging the app/ not installing it from store? How to fix this exception?

The copy of the file should be possible with `Windows.Storage.CopyAsync(IStroageFolder, ...)`. InstalledLocation is from type `StorageFolder`. Does somebody have some experience if it is allowed or will I get sth. like a security exception?

Comment: That's not possible, Metro apps must use isolated storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstalledLocation is read-only, but you can write to application's data storage folder (ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder).

This works:

```
var fop = new FileOpenPicker();
fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
StorageFile file = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
    await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```

It might also be necessary to check library access capabilities in your application manifest.

Comment: Thx4ur answer. Unfortunately I need writing access to the InstalledLocation, but it seems as if it can not be done in metro. Anyway I'll accept your answer to close this question.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you need write access to your binaries/assets?

Comment: I'm using MEF. Loading external portable dlls is not possible in Metro. But it's possible to load portable dlls which are located in the installDirectory. Currently I've to copy these dll's while bulding the app. But I dream of a user who can choose in the core app, which dll's he want to load and also add own dlls etc. This would be possible with Filepicker -> select dll -> copy to installedLocation -> Load dll/addin with MEF.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?